# What is the significance of h in first principles differentiation?

Tags: calculus

I have been looking for an answer to this question for my assignment. What is the significance of h in first principles differentiation? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

On the curve $y=f(x)$, the line through $(a,\,f(a))$ and $(a+h,\,f(a+h))$ for $h\ne 0$ has gradient $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$. (This line is called a secant; don't try connecting this to the function $\sec\theta$.) As $|h|$ gradually shrinks, this line slides until it becomes a tangent to the curve at $(a,\,f(a))$, and its gradient becomes $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$, the definition of $f^\prime(a)$. The significance of $h$ is a small difference between two points' $x$-coordinates.