# The Gradient Function

Tags: calculus

Why do the gradient function gives gradient to for a curve for any point?

For example, if y=x^3 is a curve, why 3x^2 (another curve) give gradient for x^3 at all points on x^3?

Comment: This was one of Newton/Leibniz's big insights! Does this answer help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243744/what-is-the-significance-of-h-in-first-principles-differentiation